# Using existing sqlite database in Android - "No such table" error

Tags: android, database, sqlite

This question has been asked tenths of times before. But I have spent a good 6 hours looking at previous answers trying to solve this problem. I have found no solution. The same error remains:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Test (code 1):
>   , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Test

**Instructions that should work, but does not, include:**

[How to use an existing database with an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application)

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

http://mobisys.in/blog/2012/01/tutorial-using-database-in-android-applications/

I create an SQLite database using this tool http://sqlitebrowser.org/, and put it in the assets folder as you should do. Here is a screenshot of my database.
http://postimg.org/image/wuvw8xwcv/

Here is my code, following the first link.

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
package com.example.johan.databas;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    private static String TAG = "DatabaseHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat window
    //destination path (location) of our database on device
    private static String DB_PATH = "";
    private static String DB_NAME ="db1";// Database name
    private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
    private final Context mContext;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);// 1? its Database Version
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17){
            DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
        }
        else
        {
            DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        }
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException
    {
        //If database not exists copy it from the assets

        boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
        if(!mDataBaseExist)
        {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            this.close();
            try
            {
                //Copy the database from assests
                copyDataBase();
                Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");
            }
            catch (IOException mIOException)
            {
                throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
            }
        }
    }
    //Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/Da Name
    private boolean checkDataBase()
    {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        //Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    //Copy the database from assets
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
    {
        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0)
        {
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        }
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    }

    //Open the database, so we can query it
    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException
    {
        String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        //Log.v("mPath", mPath);
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        //mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
        return mDataBase != null;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close()
    {
        if(mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

}
```

**TestAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.johan.databas;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

public class TestAdapter
{
    protected static final String TAG = "DataAdapter";

    private final Context mContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;

    public TestAdapter(Context context)
    {
        this.mContext = context;
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
    }

    public TestAdapter createDatabase() throws SQLException
    {
        try
        {
            mDbHelper.createDataBase();
        }
        catch (IOException mIOException)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, mIOException.toString() + "  UnableToCreateDatabase");
            throw new Error("UnableToCreateDatabase");
        }
        return this;
    }

    public TestAdapter open() throws SQLException
    {
        try
        {
            mDbHelper.openDataBase();
            mDbHelper.close();
            mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        }
        catch (SQLException mSQLException)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "open >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
            throw mSQLException;
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void close()
    {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    public Cursor getTestData()
    {
        try
        {
            String sql ="SELECT * FROM Test";

            Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
            if (mCur!=null)
            {
                mCur.moveToNext();
            }
            return mCur;
        }
        catch (SQLException mSQLException)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
            throw mSQLException;
        }
    }
}
```

I have uninstalled an reinstalled the app, I have tried it on both emulator and physical device on both mac and windows. I have played around with having and leaving out the .sql extension. I have tried other's databases as well as trying my own.

Seriously, what I have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to connect and use an external database inside one of my android app.

```
File sdcardDir = new File(System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE"), "myAppFolder");
    File spatialDbFile = new File(sdcardDir, "myexternaldb.sqlite");
    sDatabase = new Database();
    try {
        sDatabase.open(spatialDbFile.getAbsolutePath(), jsqlite.Constants.SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE
                | jsqlite.Constants.SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE);

        message.setText("db at " + spatialDbFile.getAbsolutePath() + "  open succeed");
    } catch (jsqlite.Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Then you can use the sDatabase to execute queries.